# Adding an array element together

Tags: java

As you can see below elements [1] and elements[2] have both been converted to integers, I was wondering if it is possible to add then together each time the while loop goes around. For example elements 1 is the score of each game so I was wondering if it is possible to add each game score together to get the total score of all the games which have been entered by the user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class REQ1
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {

     String playername;      
     String line;
     String[] list = new String[100];
     int count = 0;  
     int score;
     int time;


     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 


      System.out.println("Please enter your name");

      playername = sc.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Please enter your game achivements (Game name:score:time played) E.g. Minecraft:14:2332");

      while (count < 100){

             line = sc.nextLine();

             if(line.equals("quit")){
                  break;
                  }

             list[count]=line;
            System.out.println("list[count]" + list[count]);

            count++;

         }   

        System.out.println("Player : "+playername);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
      for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
          line=list[i];
          String[] elements =line.split(":");             
          score=Integer.parseInt(elements[1].trim());
          time=Integer.parseInt(elements[2].trim());



          System.out.println("Game:" +elements[0]+ " Score= "+elements[1]+" Minutes Played= "+elements[2]);

      }



}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is absolutely possible.
You can just do something like  this

```
      int totalScore = 0; //INITIAlISE THE VAR TOTAL SCORE
      for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
      line=list[i];
      String[] elements =line.split(":");             
      score=Integer.parseInt(elements[1].trim());
      time=Integer.parseInt(elements[2].trim());
      totalScore = totalScore + score;// ADD THIS LINE


          System.out.println("Game:" +elements[0]+ " Score= "+elements[1]+" Minutes Played= "+elements[2]);

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      score+=Integer.parseInt(elements[1].trim());
      time+=Integer.parseInt(elements[2].trim());
```